# How does java Random() find a seed?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

from my research everyone seems to say that java random uses the system time in milliseconds as its default seed when one is not specified. So, following this if we have the system time at the moment a random number is generated we should be able to know what seed generates that number.
So,

```
(new Random()).nextLong;
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
(new Random(time)).nextLong
```

should produce two identical numbers as the seed is the same, right? It doesn't so either it doesn't use TimeMillis as the seed or I'm doing something else wrong.

Thanks so much for any help, I've searched for hours but can't seem to find a consistent answer. I just want to know exactly how it finds a seed when one is not specified. My thinking is maybe it does use the system time but it multiplies it etc before coming to a final seed.

Thanks again :)

Comment: I'd say, since the random function takes time, the `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not the same as when it was used for the seed of the first random.

Comment: Anyway people seem to not realize that [the source code for the standard library is readily available](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L104) and mostly very easy to read.

Comment: I checked the time before and after and got the same time for both, so it shouldn't be that

Comment: Federico where could I find it? I searched for a while and somehow only found an older version, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java used to use the system time as the default seed, up to 1.4.2. In 1.5 this "bug" was fixed. Compare the [1.4.2 API specification](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()):

> Creates a new random number generator. Its seed is initialized to a value based on the current time:
>
> ```
> public Random() { this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }
> ```
>
> Two Random objects created within the same millisecond will have the same sequence of random numbers.

With the [1.5 API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()):

> Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.

The current implementation in OpenJDK uses a static `AtomicLong` which is updated every time you create a new `Random` instance without a seed. If you don't have the source code locally, you can find it in the [source code on github](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L104):

```
    public Random() {
        this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
    }

    private static long seedUniquifier() {
        // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
        // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
        for (;;) {
            long current = seedUniquifier.get();
            long next = current * 1181783497276652981L;
            if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
                return next;
        }
    }

    private static final AtomicLong seedUniquifier
        = new AtomicLong(8682522807148012L);
```

Comment: For interested future readers: Python uses the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) as the core generator. [Here](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~jsa8/math_project.pdf) is an interesting comparison between the two.

Comment: ahh ok thank you, so is there no way to find the seed from just the output and the time? I'm asking because I'm reviewing someone else's code and they seem to be trying to use the time to verify that the seed was properly generated. I guess from time and random output it would be possible to find the atomic long? Thanks for clearing this up for me

Comment: You can probably find the seed with some effort purely from the Random method call results, but I don't think it will be easy. You can use the reflection API to read the innards of the Random object directly.

Comment: @parad0x5983 by asking that it sounds like you need a cryptographically RNG, which `java.util.Random` is not. You could use `SecureRandom` instead